# Listing ToCharArray Method to MessageBox or TextBox

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to use the ToCharArray method to list the characters a user inputs and list those characters downwards(Vertically) in either MessageBox, or TextBox. Preferably I would like it in TextBox, but if its easier and/or better, I'd also consider the MessageBox.

This is what I currently have:

```
Dim P As String = Ques.Text
Dim L As String = P.ToCharArray()
Dim Q As String = LCase(P)
Dim QQ As String = StrReverse(Q)
Dim RP As String = StrReverse(L)
Dim chars() = P.ToCharArray()

If QQ = Q Then
    Ans.Text = "True"

Else
    Ans.Text = "False"

End If
    For index As Integer = 0 To 100
        MessageBox.Show(Ch(index))
Next
Exit Sub
```

End Sub

Comment: Do you mean you want to display the user-input vertically in a messagebox ?

Comment: What is `Ch`? Aren't you supposed to use `chars(index)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim x As String  'Holds the Userinput
    x = TextBox1.Text

    Dim VerticalText As String = ""

    For Each item In x.ToCharArray 'For each character in the array append a newLine
        VerticalText += item + vbNewLine
    Next

    TextBox2.Text = VerticalText 'Show the formatted text in another multiline textbox
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! that work perfectly and exactly how I wanted.